# Using ROS publish kinect RGB and depth data

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, my desktop is ubuntu 11.10 ROS Fuerte version. My turtlebot is ROS Electric version. I want to use turtlebot get kinect combined RGB and depth data. The data was then sent via wireless to my desktop to RGBDSLAM provide data. Do you have any good ideas? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65295/using-ros-publish-kinect-rgb-and-depth-data/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-06-19**:
Can you post more information about what you've tried so far, and what's not working for you?

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-07-02**:
Now I can get  color map and depth map on the kinect on turtlebot. But do not know how to make this information in rosbag, I would like to send this rosbag, then desktop RGBDSLAM get this rosbag, three-dimensional environment to finalize the composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try

```
rosbag record /tf /camera/depth/image_rect /camera/depth/camera_info /camera/rgb/camera_info /camera/rgb/image_rect_color
```

Don't forget to use these topics in your launchfile for rgbdslam (and set config/topic_points to an empty string), e.g.:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rgbdslam" type="rgbdslam" name="rgbdslam" cwd="node" required="true" output="log"> 
    <!-- Input data settings-->
    <param name="config/topic_image_mono"              value="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/> <!--could also be color -->
    <param name="config/topic_image_depth"             value="/camera/depth/image_rect"/>
    <param name="config/topic_points"                  value=""/> <!--if empty, poincloud will be reconstructed from image and depth -->

    <param name="config/feature_detector_type"         value="SURF"/>
    <param name="config/feature_extractor_type"        value="SURF"/>
    <param name="config/max_keypoints"                 value="600"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3